# List of system tables in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to filter all the tables in a SQLite database based on if they are system tables or user generated ones.

So far I've found out that they are the ones with the *sqlite_* prefix and AllDataTypes.

Has anyone done something like this? Is there a list of them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is only one system table that is of any consequence.

```
select * from sqlite_master
```

but you may get some useful information from `sqlite_sequence`,

Comment: Yes, but I need to filter them all. I have to have the means to get all the non system tables.

Comment: there is also the `sqlite_temp_master`

Answer (score 10):

I think it can be filtered by name (as you already done)

I've used script

```
SELECT 
  name, type
FROM 
  sqlite_master
WHERE 
  type in ('table', 'view')
AND 
  name not like 'sqlite?_%' escape '?'
```

Answer (score 1):

sqlite_autoindex_TABLE_N - which will have information  UNIQUE and PRIMARY KEY constraints on ordinary table.

sqlite_statN - which will have where N is an integer. Such tables store database statistics gathered by the ANALYZE command and used by the query planner to help determine the best algorithm to use for each query.

Source : https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html

sqlite_user - this table will be present ,if we set up authentication-required database.

Source : http://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/ext/userauth/user-auth.txt