# Split table into 2 new tables by index with sqlite3 and Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a database.db file that has a table1 like this one. Note that the index is just codes and not numeric:

```
id    | item | price
-------------
 45f5 | book | 20  
 25h8 | copy | 30   
 as34 | pen  | 10 
 t674 | key  | 15 
 5h6f | ring | 25 
 67yu | mug  | 40
```

and I would like to create two additional tables in my dababase.db names table2 and table3 in which one contain the first 4 rows and the other one the last 2 rows:

table2

```
id    | item | price
-------------
 45f5 | book | 20  
 25h8 | copy | 30   
 as34 | pen  | 10 
 t674 | key  | 15
```

table3

```
id    | item | price
-------------
 5h6f | ring | 25 
 67yu | mug  | 40
```

I have been trying with CREATE TABLE but I have too many columns in table1 to write it one by one. What would be your approach to this problem? Thanks!

```sql
CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE condition
```

Comment: Just write the statements manually or copy the data from the SQLite 3 system tables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858519/list-of-system-tables-in-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

To create table you have to specify name of column and type,
`SELECT * FROM` already exisitig will not work. See https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

You can try to create such table based on already existing table like:

```
INSERT INTO table2  SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE condition;
```

Try to use above statement without WHERE to check whether it works as I don't have access now to SQLite database to check it.