# How to check if a table within a .sqlite file exists using C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am creating a WPF program where the user can create lists of products that are stored in an .sqlite database. Each product list has it's own table inside the database, who's name is chosen by the user. I need to figure out if the table already exists when I try to create them so that if they do I can ask the user to choose a different name.

I know

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{table_name}';
```

is the query used to check if a table exists but how do I get this statement in boolean form using c#?

I would assume something similar to

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=filepath;Version=3");
sql = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{table_name}';"
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
command.something();
```

But I am unsure what function of `command` to use to get the Boolean value of this query and how to format it.

Comment: Well, don't use ExecuteNonQuery() if you want a result. You can select the count and see if it's greater than 0. You could also get a data reader and see if the `HasRows` property is true.

Comment: Like in this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8 , you need a reader to read the result of your query. 
Don&#39;t use ExecuteNonQuery if you execute a query ;)

Comment: I am unsure what to use instead of ExecuteNonQuery(). How do I select the count? the count of how many tables is in the database is no good to me as there might be several tables of different names to the one the user's creating. and HasRow's could prove an issue in theory if the user tried to recreate a table that already existed but was empty?

Comment: It looks like using readers is probably a step in the right direction of what I want to do but how would i syntax it in c# to read the query of if a table exists, given an sqliteconnection and a table name?

Comment: Think you need to interrogate a [system table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858519/list-of-system-tables-in-sqlite) to see if a particular user table has been created.

Comment: Look at the sqlite count() function. Or ignore that approach and look at one of the zillion webpage results that come back from a `c# sqlite data reader` google search.

Comment: Here's the [English version of the SQLCommand object docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitecommand?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0).  It is worth looking at documentation or the object explorer to see what other methods are available on an object.  It is okay to ask question, but often the answers can be discovered by exploring the object model... and you might learn more by exploring.

Comment: @CPerkins I appreciate its usually easier to find the information on documentation but from my understanding data reader is mainly for reading data inside a table so I didn't know it would be able to be used to see if a table exists as its not an explicit Doestableexist command.

Comment: Although `sqlite_master ` is a special built-in table (a table which contains meta data about other tables), it is a table nonetheless and the SQL syntax is identical to querying any other table.  The information will be returned in the same way that a query to any other table would be.  That's okay if you didn't recognize that, but that is how a good DBMS works--utilizing the same data model for meta-data as other data (unlike other systems which require a special programming object model to get meta data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns -1 for SELECT statements, so it would be inappropriate to use it in this case.

try using `ExecuteReader()`, which returns a [SqliteDataReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitedatareader?view=msdata-sqlite-2.0.0) class that contains the `HasRows` property, in which should be true in case of a non-empty result set.

the code:

```
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=filepath;Version=3");
sql = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='{table_name}';"
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);

try 
{
  var result = command.ExecuteReader();

  if (result.HasRows) 
  {
    // INSERT statement here
  }

}
catch (Exception e) 
{
  throw e;
}
```